# Is there a way to upload a new version of apk which will not show up as an update to users who have already downloaded the app?

Tags: android, apk

Here is the scenario we are in:
We recently pushed an apk to the play store - the manifest file has the maxsdk version set as 26.  This means that for the users  with version 8.1 of Android does not see the app for download on the play store.
What we want to do is create another apk without the maxsdk version and upload to playstore replacing the existing one - no change in code as we have already tested the apk with version 8.1.  However, we are concerned that the users who have already downloaded the app will get an "update" which is not really an update.
Can someone suggest the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Next time use targetSdkVersion and no maxSdkVersion since it will keep working for new platforms.

Comment: Yes, we realised that a little too late!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by uploading an APK with minSdkVersion=27, and include the previous APK in the release, i.e. you'll have both APKs in the release but your existing users won't be eligible to release the new APK so won't see the update.

Then, in your next "real" release, you go back to your normal minSdkVersion and go back to a single APK per release.

It's a bit hacky but achieves what you want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: We ended up doing just that - though it is a bit hacky as you suggest. It was not a feasibility to release a new version within hours of the previous one. Another lesson learned is never to use the maxSdkVersion unless absolutely necessary! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to simply release a proper update, which in the version description simply says that you added support for Android 8.1. If you're updating the SDK, you are indeed making an update, and this sort of 'update' is commonplace.

Users won't be put off by the fact that there's an update that is exclusive to a particular Android version (which they may not have), as it will show that you're committed to supporting the latest firmware.